# Heap corruption with function pointer on Solaris 64-bits

Tags: c, function-pointers, solaris

I have the following C code on Solaris 5.10 64-bits compiled with CC 5.10 with flags *-m64 -KPIC -x04*

*header.h*

```
typedef struct functions
{
   double (* pfComputeGeneric) (myStruct *, myStruct *, double, double *, int);
} functions;

...

double myCompute(myStruct *, myStruct *, double, double *, int);
```

*source.c*

```
double myCompute(myStruct * px1, myStruct *px2, double d1, double *pd1, int i1)
{
    // Do stuff with px1
}

...

myStruct *pxStruct = alloc(...);    
functions *pxFunctions = alloc(...);
pxFunctions->pfComputeGeneric = myCompute;

...

double dResult += pxFunctions->pfComputeGeneric(pxStruct, pxStruct, 0.0, NULL, 0);
```

The code in *source.c* runs fine (nothing weird) until I enter enter into *myCompute* through function pointer *pfCompute*, where *px1* gets corrupted. I don't know why.

Replacing the call through *pfCompute* by a direct call to *myCompute* solves the issue.

Removing the *-x04* option also solves the issue.

I had a look at the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593732/solaris-64-bit-function-pointer-problem%22this%20question%22) but I'm sure I'm not messing with pointer sizes.

Comment: There is a semicolon missing after `} functions` .

Comment: Perhaps the allocations are wrong, or something dodgy is going on in the parts you omitted. Please edit your question to include the allocations, or better yet: Post an [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: maybe the function wasn't expecting to receive px1 and px2 both pointing to the same memory?

Comment: @NisseEngström That was my first guess: I've checked on Windows 32-bits, Linux 32-bits and 64-bits and on Solaris 32-bits. The code runs fine on all these platforms. Purify/Dr. Memory do not complain either.
I'm suspecting a side effect (a bug ?) of option (*-x04*) there. I cannot really include the full code (this is a highly-simplified version of a code that has a few hundred lines of code). Actually, posting this problem, I wanted to know if using function pointers on Solaris 64-bits with *-x04* had some known issues.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: *px1* is corrupted when entering the function, before any processing happens. The code works basically on every environment I could put my hands on but Solaris 64-bits...

Comment: That would suggest your alloc function is broken

Comment: I was not really clear (I've updated the code). I really think *alloc()* is fine because I am able to use *px1* before entering the function. Calling *pfCompute* with *px1* as argument somehow corrupts it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is indeed an issue of *-x04*. When I look at the assemby call, I see:

```
...
0x0000000000987eb2: myCaller+0x081a:  movq     0xfffffffffffffe28(%rbp),%rcx
0x0000000000987eb9: myCaller+0x0821:  movq     $0x0000000000000006,%rax
0x0000000000987ec0: myCaller+0x0828:  movq     0xfffffffffffffe08(%rbp),%rdi
0x0000000000987ec7: myCaller+0x082f:  call     *0x0000000000000018(%rdi)
0x0000000000987eca: myCaller+0x0832:  addq     $0x0000000000000010,%rsp
```

So the compiler uses *%rdi* (!) to get the real adress of *myCompute* from *pxFunctions*. And in 64-bits, *%rdi* is used to store the first argument of a function, hence the alteration.

Comment: In C++ the first argument to the function is the _this_ pointer.  Above you say you are using *CC* (Solaris C++ compiler) - is that true or did you really mean *cc* (Solaris C compiler)?

Comment: I am using CC (c++). I said C code because I'm not using C++ features (though there is not much difference between class methods and function pointers stored in structs). Are you saying that *%rdi* holds a pointer to *pxFunctions*, which is pushed *@myCaller+0x0828* (as `this`), and that *0x18(%rdi)* is the adress of `this->pfComputeGeneric` ?